# SQL return result on empty query

Tags: sql

So I have a simple query as follows;

> SELECT Name FROM Contact WHERE Age > @age

My question is, I want this query to always return a value. If there are no results the SQL query is suppose to return **' '** (blank space).

I have added a UNION SELECT at the end;

> SELECT Name FROM Contact WHERE Age > @age UNION SELECT ' '

However this also adds the blank record when there is a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT Name FROM Contact WHERE Age > @age)
BEGIN 
SELECT '' AS age
END
ELSE 
BEGIN 
SELECT Name FROM Contact WHERE Age > @age
END
```

This will check if a result set will return and if nothing will, select a blank space and name the field age.

Comment: Your suggestion works thank you ! Do you think there might be a way without using if else statements ?

Comment: @0014 What other restrictions do you have?

Comment: What do you mean by other restrictions ? There are no other restrictions.

Comment: So your only restriction is that you can't use if/else?

Comment: No I can use if/else statements. Just wondering if there was any other way without it.

Comment: Yeah there is, but this is the cleanest way. The other ways I can think of would be very muddy.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this all in a single query:

```
select name
from contacts
where age > @age
union all
select v.name
from (values ('')) v.name
where not exists (select 1 from contacts where age > @age);
```

Or using a CTE:

```
with t as (
      select name
      from contacts
      where age > @age
     )
select t.*
from t
union all
select v.name
from (values ('')) v(name)
where not exists (select 1 from t);
```

Or, the fun way using a `left join`:

```
select coalesce(c.name, v.name) as name
from (values ('')) v(name) left join
     contacts c
     on c.age > @age;
```

Comment: Perfect answer! This was what I was actually looking for.

Comment: @0014 . . . If this is your preferred answer, then you should accept it.

Comment: I haven't specified that I was looking for a single query in my question. So the answer that I selected deserved to be selected. But only because he was faster than you to answer the question...